# UIImageViews and related view controllers for photo gallery

Tags: iphone, ios, foundation

I have a list of UIImageViews that I'd like to flick through, much like Facebook's image viewer. Any suggestions on which controller I should use a page controll with custom view controllers or does anyone know of an open library that would help accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The perfect open library for this is [Three20](http://three20.info/).  It is the API used by the Facebook app itself and is updated regularly and very robust.

Inside it, there is a TTThumbsViewController and a TTPhotoViewController that sound like what you'll be using.

Here is a good tutorial that goes over TTPhotoViewController (and Thumbs can be basically substituted instead) [PhotoViewController Tutorial - Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer)